# Questions regarding GitHub Enterprise upgrade from 2.2.4 to 2.3.3

Tags: upgrade, github-enterprise

I am planning to upgrade our GitHub Enterprise from 2.2.4 to the latest 2.3.3. Reviewing the upgrade document here:https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.3/admin/guides/installation/upgrading-the-github-enterprise-virtual-machine/

I have two questions so far:

1. "Download the upgrade package", the official download page for
   VMWare 2.3.3 is a full .ova file, not a .pkg file as in the doc.
2. Do I need to create the "target root partition" /dev/xvda2 as in the doc beforehand?

I have a 3rd question:

3. As the backup solution, I am taking a VM snapshot before upgrade, shall I put the GitHub into Maintenance Mode before taking the VM snapshot?

Thanks
Jirong

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade was successful. Here is the answers:
1. Copy the URL from the Upgrade tab, not Install.
2. No.